# accessing a variable outside a Requesthandler

Tags: html, css, tornado

i'm using CSS3 accordion effect, and i want to detect if a hacker will 
make a script to make a parallel request; ie: 
i've a login form and a registration form in the same page, but only 
one is visible because there is a CSS3: to access the page, the user 
agent must be HTML5 compatible. 
the tip i use is:

```
class Register(tornado.web.RequestHandler): 
    def post(self): 
        tt = self.get_argument("_xsrf") + str(time.time()) 
        rtime = float(tt.replace(self.get_argument("_xsrf"), "")) 
        print rtime 
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler): 
    def post(self): 
        tt = self.get_argument("_xsrf") + str(time.time()) 
        ltime = float(tt.replace(self.get_argument("_xsrf"), "")) 
        print ltime
```

i've used the `xsrf` variable because it's unique for every user, to 
avoid making the server think that the request is coming from the same 
machine. 
now what i want: how to make the difference between time values: 
`abs(ltime - rtime)` ; mean, how do i access to rtime outside the class, 
i just know how to access the value outside the method, i want to make 
this operation to detect if the value is small, then the user is using 
a script to make a parallel request to kill the server! 
in other words (for general python users) 
if i have:

```
class Product: 
   def info(self): 
       self.price = 1000 
   def show(self): 
       print self.price 
>>> car = Product() 
>>> car.info() 
>>> car.show() 

1000
```

but what if i've another

```
class User: 
    pass
```

then how do make a method that prints me the self.price, i've tried 
inheritance, but got error: AttributeError: User instance has no 
attribute '`price`', so only methods are passed, not attributs?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to understand Model objects and patterns that use persistant storage of data.  `tornado.web.RequestHandler` and any object that you subclass from it only exists for the duration of your request.  From when the URL is received on the server to when data is sent back to the browser via a `self.write()` or `self.finish()`.

I would recommend you look at some of the Django or [Flask tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/) for some basic ideas of how to build a MVC application in Python (There is no Tornado Tutorials that cover this that I know of).

Comment: thank you :D so, from what i understand, there is no way to avoid the parallel execution of the both handlers?

Comment: In tornado execution is serial unless you yield it via the @asynchronous decorator on a get()/post()/ request handler method.  Since it isn't multithreaded you still only have one execution path even if decorated.

Comment: but if i use the technique of getting the time, if it's not executed then it's zero, else, it will be a value, and if it's a value, this value must not be too small, this is the idea i got

Comment: If you're overloading xsrf for session management - you should look into using ``self.set_secure_cookie(...)`` [Cookies](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#cookies-and-secure-cookies) for managing session state.

Comment: xsrf is only a hack here to get an unique id to not mixte between the same requesthandlers that users can call at the same time.